# Spring application not showing table in website

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm working on a Spring boot application which functions as a wishlist. I've made a login feature that logs in with a username only - and i've created and connected a mySQL database where the users and wishes are stored.
When i log in as a user ,however, I cannot view the table with the wishes I've added - and I simply can't figure out what is exactly wrong.

The table itself in the HTML looks like this:

```
  ` <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Hvad ønsker du dig?</th>
        <th>Beskrivelse(fx. farve, str, etc.)</th>
        <th>Link(Valgfrit)</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr th:each="oenske: ${oensker}">
        <td th:text="${oenske.navn}"/>
        <td th:text="${oenske.beskrivelse}"/>
        <td th:text="${oenske.link}"/>

        <td>
            <a th:href="@{'/sletØnske/'+${oenske.bruger_id}}">
                <button class="btn-sletØnske" id="btn-sletØnske">Slet dette ønske</button>
            </a>
            <a th:href="@{'/redigerØnske/'+${oenske.bruger_id}}">
                <button class="btn-redigerØnske" id="btn-redigerØnske">Rediger</button>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
     </tbody>

 </table>`
```

The controller class in which a fetchAll() method is run looks like this:

```
   ` @GetMapping("/createOenskeseddel")
    public String index(Model model) {
        List<Ønske> ønskeList= ønskeService.fetchAll();
        model.addAttribute("oensker",ønskeList);
        return "redirect:Home/createOenskeseddel";
    }    `
```

And the coresponding fetchAll() method in the repository looks like this:

```
   ` public List<Ønske> fetchAll() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM oenske INNER JOIN bruger ON oenske.bruger_id =                             bruger.bruger_id";
        RowMapper<Ønske> rowMapper = new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Ønske.class);
        return template.query(sql, rowMapper);
    }`
```

I've tried using the html code on different sites, but with the same results. In my IDE it tells me it cannot resolve "oensker" - which most likely is at the root of the cause.

Comment: Do you need `return "redirect:Home/createOenskeseddel"`? Why not just `return "your_thymeleaf_template_name_without_the_suffix"`? (I don't know the template name.)

Comment: Minor point: You have a malformed HTML table - three `<th>` columns but four `<td>` columns.